# How is Mechanical Turk Bounding Box Data Formatted in Bulk?

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, mechanicalturk, yolo

I am attempting to use YOLOv3 to train a classifier with data that I get from MTurk. I have used a Sandbox to see how the data from 1 individual HIT is formatted. I have no problem writing code to parse the JSON strings that Amazon Mechanical Turk provides, but I would like to know before paying for the services. So I know how to format the project and any other variables I need to add.

I can see the format for 1 task, but I would like to do 50 or 60 tasks and see how MTurk presents the data. If someone has an example of multiple HITs, I would be grateful.

[image: HIT Task]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is given in a CSV file with your annotations in a JSON string and image width and height. Each image is associated with its row.

Here is an [example file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SVgg7RFfs5lY0stu-oKORrLDGGnM1Jl3/view?usp=sharing) with a couple of columns removed.

One thing to note is there doesn't seem to be a way in Mturk to view the annotations before approval. May need to do a little python magic to make it easier to see the quality of the annotations.